# Cron issue with apc cache

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1, cron, apc

When i try to launch cron on magento 1.9.0.1 in crontab, I have this error :

...can't get apc memory size...

In my apc.ini, I have "apc.enabled=1", "apc.enable_cli = 0".

I know, I need to have "apc.enable_cli = 1" but I can't, instead I use :

/usr/bin/php -f /www/cron.php -d "apc.enable_cli=1"

But it doesn't work. It's really strange because on magento 1.7 this trick working well.

Do you have an idea why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I found a solution to my own question. `cron.php` call `cron.sh` and `cron.sh` recall `cron.php` with specific parameters but don't care about parameter pass during the first call. I manually edit `cron.sh` and add `-d "apc.enable_cli=1"` where php command is called.

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem is, that php cli does use a different php.ini which you can find by running "php --ini"

I assume you did add it to the wrong ini